# Trying to list all the usernames if a userName value is not provided.

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="dataSource1">

</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dataSource1" SelectCommand="select UserName from  aspnet_Users where UserName = COALESCE(@userName,UserName)" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySqlProviderConnection %>">
    <SelectParameters>

        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userName" DbType="String" Direction="Input" QueryStringField="userName" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />

    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Above is my code. I am trying to list all the usernames if the default is an empty string. But it doesn't give me the result with all the usernames.

Am I missing something here?
If I run the below query in sql server management studio I do get the result I expect.

```
select UserName from  aspnet_Users where UserName = COALESCE(null,UserName)
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Nope NULL is NOT defined. Nothing is equal to null. So your query will never return.

Comment: NULL is NOT the same thing as an empty string. It is not really clear what you are trying to do here. Your query and the description seem to be pretty different from each other.

Comment: So what does ConvertEmptyStingToNull=true do here? If i pass in an empty string i want it treated as null..

Comment: @SeanLange  can elaborate on that method perhaps. Sean check the comment thread in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead.

`WHERE UserName = @userName or @userName is null`

Or if you are passing an empty string into `@userName`

`WHERE UserName = @userName or @userName =''`

Your last query, `select UserName from  aspnet_Users where UserName = COALESCE(null,UserName)`, would return all rows where the UserName isn't null which probably isn't what you were thinking it would do.

Comment: I want to return all the usernames if i pass in an empty string. Otherwise jst one row where user name is equal to the value thats passed in.

Comment: @psj01 did you try substituting this where clause in place of yours?

Comment: yes. ur query works .. but I am trying to understand why COALESCE doesn't work here....

Comment: setting ConvertEmptyStingToNull=true , should make the query ' select UserName from  aspnet_Users where UserName = COALESCE(null,UserName) ' right?... thats what I am hoping to happen...

Comment: @psj01 coalesce takes the first non null value. You have defeated it by providing a NULL. The way you used it in your last comment would work but it's not what coalesce is used for. Instead you should use isnull(@userName,UserName). However both will fails if you pass in an empty string. NULL doesn't equal a blank string. NULL doesn't even equal NULL. The only way to check for NULL is with IsNull()

Comment: That part was fine. It was your SQL that was wrong. I was just elaborating on NULL since It's handled differently in SQL than a lot of languages

Comment: but when I pass in an empty string in to the parameter I am not getting the result set with all the usernames. .. Hope I am making sense... not sure if i am making myself clear on this...  If i pass in '' in to the parameter I the query should be ' select UserName from  aspnet_Users where UserName = COALESCE(null,UserName) ', right? But I am not getting that...

Comment: I'm not a C guy so I can't elaborate on that part, but I wouldn't use COALESCE like that and if the way I provided using @userName is null also doesn't return all the usernames then your C function isn't doing what it is supposed to. Run it in debug mode in VS and see what is sent or use SQL profiler

Comment: ok I really appreciate your help :) I am gonna look in to it more once I get home ..